# Clarification of open affine neighborhood at $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

From Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra* chapter 2:

> [image]

**If $Y$ is defined by one equation $f=0$, then isn't $Y=\mathcal Z(0)=\mathbb A^r$?**

Comment: The ring of regular functions on $\Bbb{C}^2$ is $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ and the ring of regular functions on $\Bbb{C}^2- \ \Bbb{C}\times 0$ is $\Bbb{C}[x,y,y^{-1}]\cong \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]/(zy-1)$. Both have the same field of rational functions $\Bbb{C}(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "algebraic set defined by one equation $f=0$" stands for $\mathcal Z(f)$, because $\mathcal Z(f)$ is the set of the points $\xi$ such that $f(\xi)=0$.